# How to model events with locations that have a label and lat, lng coordinates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, postgis

Assume a special event is happening at this location:

```
{
  label: 'Mountain View',
  lat: 37.4224764,
  lng: -122.0842499
}
```

How would you store this information and why?

**1) Single table**

```
events: id place_label coordinates(point)
```

**2) Two separate tables**

```
events: id place_id
places: place_id label coordinates(point)
```

**3) Single table using jsonb data type**

```
events: id place(jsonb)
```

or another way?

The end goal would be to use geospatial extensions (e.g. EarthDistance, PostGIS) to do queries like "find all events within ___ miles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two separate tables otherwise you suffer the disadvantages of querying a larger table for point-in-polygon than needed.

```
CREATE TABLE places 
(
     id_place serial PRIMARY KEY,
     name     text,
     geom     geography(POINT)
);

CREATE INDEX ON places USING gist(geom);

CREATE TABLE events 
(
    id_event serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_place int    REFERENCES place,
    start_ts timestamp
);
```

> The end goal would be to use geospatial extensions (e.g. EarthDistance, PostGIS) to do queries like "find all events within ___ miles".

```
SELECT *
FROM events AS e
JOIN places AS p USING (id_place)
WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geography, miles*1609);
```

That's all events within `miles` of `(long,lat)`. I wouldn't use `earthdistance`, I would just use PostGIS.

Comment: Appreciate it, especially the use of PostGIS! Can you explain more "disadvantages of querying larger table for point-in-polygon than needed"? I am not too sure what you mean. Also how/why did you know to create index gist(geom)? I know indexes speed things up, but I am not sure when exactly I should create an index and for what. Also according to postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html, "GIN index lookups are about three times faster than GiST", wouldn't gin be more appropriate if I know I'd be reading more than writing? How did you choose?

Comment: If each event has a location, and you have a million events, that's a million point-in-polygon tests if they're hosted at 100 event-locations, then regardless of how many events you've got you'll only have to do 100 event-location tests. It's the basic advantages of a 1-to-many table.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. So you're saying that the table of places will probably be smaller than the table of events because events may share the same place? So event 1 and event 2 may both be at "this hotel", so I'd rather query the smaller table of places. If each event had a different place however, and the number of events = number of places, then another table wouldn't help, would it? I was actually going with this assumption (1 event has 1 place and no events share the same place), but I can see how your suggestion is more flexible.

Comment: Can you explain why you chose gist over gin?